# Laravel Auth return null

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm using 2 routes, one for loginUsingId(1), and the second one for test if user is logged.
When try to see Auth::id(), it is ever null.

```
//My Routes
    Route::get('/login', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'login']);

    Route::get('/test_login', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'getUser']);
```

This are the methods in UserController
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    public function login()
    {
        $auth = Auth::loginUsingId(3);
        return var_dump($auth); // <--- here return 3
    }


    public function getUser()
    {
        return response(['user'=>Auth::id()]);
    }
```

Comment: You are not logged in user

Comment: can you explain pls @sta

Comment: I checked it with `Laravel 8.25`. After logged with `Auth::loginUsingId(1)`, `Auth::id()`  returns `null` if go to other page. This is not happen if I login manually . Seems like a bug

Comment: Ok, @sta thanks for reply. What you mean with "login manually"?

Comment: I mean "login manually", if I login with `127.0.0.1:8000/login` 
 May I know your laravel version?

Comment: laravel version is 8.19

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply middleware to work `Auth::user()`

```php
Route::get('/test_login', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'getUser'])->middleware('auth');
```

then try

Comment: with middleware('auth') it redirect me to route named 'login' without pass trought controller

Comment: it's means your not login

Comment: yes sure, but I dont understand why, becouse I've used $auth = Auth::loginUsingId(3);
        return var_dump($auth); and than it returned 3

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the default Auth middleware it's not gonna work.
Although, remember there is the
`auth()->user()`
method that you can try instead ; it's more convenient as you don't need to import any model to use it.

Comment: means no one is logged in